# LDAP query with FILTER

Tags: delphi, active-directory, ldap, delphi-2007

Suppose I have the following LDAP query:

```
Base DN: OU=Groups,DC=office,DC=domain,DC=org
Filter: (member:1.2.840.113556.1.4.1941:=CN=adam smith,OU=Users,DC=office,DC=domain,DC=org)
```

How can I execute it under Delphi(2007)? Examples using ADO seem to have SQL'ish syntax and I do not now how to convert it?

Answer (score 4):

In Delphi, you can use two ways of getting at your data:

- either the "SQL'ish" syntax you describe - basically ADO access to Active Directory. That's easy, if you have a SQL background, but it's also limited in some ways (e.g. you cannot get at multi-valued attributes and such). You'll find some [Search Tips on ADO](http://www.rlmueller.net/ADOSearchTips.htm) on Richard Mueller's site (AD Programming MVP)
- import the ActiveDs.tlb type library and use the COM interfaces (most notably [`IDirectorySearch`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa746362%28VS.85%29.aspx)) provided by ADSI to search. It's a rather messy COM interface, that's probably why most tend to use the ADO search stuff which is more readily approachable

Way back when I was still programming Delphi, I did a lot of Active Directory stuff and puts some of my Delphi / AD tips and some sample code [onto my site](http://adsi.mvps.org/adsi/Delphi/index.html). It's not been updated in quite a while though :-( But the ADSISearch component might be of interest to you (and other Delphites)

*Update:* can you try this "SQL-ish" statement in your TADOCommand??

```
SELECT sAMAccountName, displayName 
FROM 'LDAP://OU=Groups,DC=office,DC=domain,DC=org' 
WHERE objectCategory='group'
  AND member:1.2.840.113556.1.4.1941:=(CN=adam smith,OU=Users,DC=office,DC=domain,DC=org)
```

Comment: Thank you for your repy! I really need to run only one query ( the one that I posted above). If someone is able to re-write it so that I can use it TADOCommand...?

Comment: Yes, but 1.2.840.113556.1.4.1941 (LDAP_MATCHING_RULE_IN_CHAIN) gives me ALL groups that user belongs to (not only those from memberof) - this happens when groups are members of other grous - I need them ALL.

Answer (score 0):

Desicion for your question:

```
var ADOConnection, ADOCmd, Res: Variant;

ADOConnection := CreateOleObject('ADODB.Connection');
ADOCmd := CreateOleObject('ADODB.Command');
try
  ADOConnection.Provider := 'ADsDSOObject';
  ADOConnection.Open('Active Directory Provider');
  ADOCmd.ActiveConnection := ADOConnection;
  ADOCmd.Properties('Page Size')     := 100;
  ADOCmd.Properties('Timeout')       := 30;
  ADOCmd.Properties('Cache Results') := False;

  sBase       := '<GC://' + sADForestName+ '>';
  sFilter     := '(&(objectCategory=person)(objectClass=user)' +
                   '(distinguishedName=' + sADUserName + ')' +
                   '(memberOf:1.2.840.113556.1.4.1941:=' + sADGroupName + '))';
  sAttributes := 'sAMAccountName';

  ADOCmd.CommandText := sBase + ';' + sFilter + ';' + sAttributes + ';subtree';
  Res := AdoCmd.Execute;

  if Res.EOF then User := ''
             else User := Res.Fields[0].Value;
finally
  ADOCmd := NULL;
  ADOConnection.Close;
  ADOConnection := NULL;
end;
```